# apache2 mod_rewrite not working for index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am working on a project which requires vine like links For ex.

I found out that this can be done via apache 2 Module called `mod_rewrite`. So, i created the `.htaccess` file and placed in `root/v/`.

.htacess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /c/
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^c/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

In the folder `/root/v/` there is a script called `index.php` which accept a variable called `page`. With this i was hoping that i can do something like:

```
http://webpage.com/c/tw3fN2
```

and apache will call the link

```
http://webpage.com/c/index.php?page=tw3fN2
```

But i does not work. Is there any mistake i am making here or forgettting something simple.

Comment: So you've put the htaccess file in a directory called **v**, and you're attempting to access it via a path called **c**?

Comment: Depending on your `mod_rewrite` version you might want to check [LogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) or [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) to troubleshoot where your `.htaccess` fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the error with the following in the .htaccess file and putting the file in the root directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/c/([^/]+)/?$    [NC]
RewriteRule .*       c/index.php?key=%1 [L]
```

Thanks guys for responding.
Appreciate it